# Reducing the system $x_1+kx_2-x_3=0$, $-x_1+x_2+k^2x_3=0$, $x_1+kx_2+(k-2)x_3=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

I can't seem to figure out how to reduce this system of equations:

$$\begin{align}
x_1+kx_2-\phantom{(k-2)}x_3 &=0 \\
-x_1+\phantom{k}x_2+\phantom{(k-)}k^2x_3 &=0 \\
x_1+kx_2+(k-2)x_3 &=0
\end{align}$$

I put them into a matrix and solved it down to:

$$\begin{align}
x_1+kx_2-\phantom{2}x_3 &=0 \\
-10x_1-8x_2-2x_3 &=0 \\
(k-3)x_3 &=0
\end{align}$$

but I'm not sure where to go from there. I'm trying to figure out if there is a unique solution or infinitely many.

Comment: Your solved matrix tells you enough.  First, what does it show $x_3$ equals?  What does it imply when you sub that value of $x_3$ into your initial system of equations?

Comment: USE `$$` instead of $ to align at center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduce the matrix to the triangular form

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & k & -1 \\ 0 & k+1 & k^2-1\\0& 0 & k-1\end{array}\right).$$

If $k\ne \pm 1$ then the RREF has three pivots so there is unique solution, $(0,0,0)$. If $k=1$ or $k=-1$ then there are only two pivots, so the system has infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

An homogeneous system has non trivial solutions if the determinant of the matrix $A$ of the coefficients is $0$. In this case
$$k^2-1=0$$
Two cases:

- $k=-1$,
  $$A=\left(
  \begin{array}{ccc}
   1 & -1 & -1 \\
   -1 & 1 & 1 \\
   1 & -1 & -3 \\
  \end{array}
  \right)$$
  The system can be reduced as
  $$\left\{
  \begin{array}{lll}
   x_1-x_2-x_3=0 \\
   x_1-x_2-3x_3=0 \\
  \end{array}
  \right.$$
  Solutions are $k\,(1,1,0),\;\forall k\in\mathbb{R}$
- $k=1$

$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & -1 \\
 -1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
The system becomes
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
 x_1+x_2-x_3=0 \\
 x_1-x_2-x_3=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.$$
Solutions are $k\,(1,0,1),\;\forall k\in\mathbb{R}$.